# When the Polynomial is bounded The coefficients are bounded

Tags: polynomials, lagrange-interpolation

The actual question is as follows:

Suppose you have a sequence of polynomials of degree $n$,

$$P_j(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_{jk}\,x^k\rightarrow P(x) $$

which is bounded in $n+1$ points for $x$ for all $j$.Prove that the sequence of coefficients $a_{jk}\rightarrow a$ is also bounded . I am supposed to be able to prove it with the Lagrange representation of the polynomial. Yet I don't even have a clue where to begin.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not quite what you are looking for, but here is a more abstract approach which circumvents looking at any formulas.

Define a linear map $Ev$ from the space of polynomials of degree at most $n$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, sending $P(x)$ to $(P(x_0),P(x_2),\dots,P(x_n))$ where the $x_i$ are the $n+1$ points you mentioned. Note that this map is invertible since it is between vector spaces of the same dimension and has a trivial kernel as a polynomial of degree at most $n$ can only vanish at $n+1$ points if it is the zero polynomial.

Now the condition that the $P_j(x)$ are bounded at these $n+1$ points means the images of the $P_j(x)$ under $Ev$ are contained inside a bounded region $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.  But then all the $P_j(x)$ are contained in $Ev^{-1}(U)$ which is bounded as it is the image of a bounded region under the linear map $Ev^{-1}$.

Comment: I like this prove it is very comprehensible, but probably not what my professor is looking for , since it is a seminar in analysis.

Comment: Well I'd argue that this is the functional analytic approach to this problem, but yea probably not the kind of analysis your professor is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Lagrange polynomials can be used to *compute* the coefficients of a degree-$n$ polynomial $p(x)$, given $p(x_1), \dots, p(x_{n + 1})$ for distinct values $x_1, \dots, x_{n + 1}$. For your problem, you are effectively trying to *bound* the coefficients of $p(x)$, given *bounds* on $p(x_1), \dots, p(x_{n + 1})$. In other words, roughly, you are supposed to show that the Lagrange interpolation procedure is not wildly sensitive to small changes to its input data.

Comment: I am not sure I follow , is it self evident ,when I input the variables $x_1,x_2 ...$ into the Lagrange formula? In our lecture we use the formula $P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nP(x_k).q_k(x)$,with$q_k(x)=\prod_{j=0}^n(x-x_j)/(x_k-x_j)$

Comment: Right, so each coefficient of $P(x)$ is of the form $\sum_{k = 0}^n P(x_k) a_k$, where $a_k$ is the corresponding coefficient of $q_k$. From this formula, it shouldn't be too hard to show that if the $P(x_k)$ values are allowed to vary over a bounded set, then the coefficients of $P(x)$ will be bounded.

Comment: Of course, thank you for the quick response.